# Temperature distribution of air around a rocket

Tags: rockets, simulation, temperature, sub-orbital, thermodynamics

I am doing some simulations in ANSYS Fluent of a rocket traveling at speed of 100 m/s at an altitude of 12000 m where the surroundings temperature is 216.7 K. The image above is the temperature distribution of the air around the rocket. Does it make sense to have the highest temperature located at the bottom of the rocket? If so, what would be the explanation?

[image: Air temperature distribution of a rocket at 12000 m traveling at speed of 100 m/s]

Comment: What data are you comparing your simulation to?

Comment: What is the temperature of the rocket body ? Is it higher than surrounding temperature (which is 216.7 K) ? Is the flow velocity available for this simulation ?

Comment: “Does it make sense to have the highest temperature located at the bottom of the rocket? If so, what would be the explanation?” Because that is where the flaming exhaust goes out?

Comment: If there's no exhaust (maybe it ran out of fuel?), this question may be better for the Physics SE.  But  the turbulence behind the blunt tail might be enough to heat that air by just those few degrees.

Comment: Not an expert in fluid dynamics but I'd say this seems reasonable: Which air gets to this place? Air that is already heated due to friction along the whole side of the rocket. Plus the additional heating due to the large amount of turbulence in this place.